# Why are some of the faces on my mesh lit up?

Tags: mesh, faces, lighting, shadows

[image]

I'm relative new to blender, and I found myself working on some models for a game.

Recently I was modeling this door, but at some point I've noticed that some of the faces are lit up for some reason.

I tried some things I knew about but none of them worked yet.
Maybe someone knows how to fix this problem

[image]

I hope this image provides more info.
I've also tried to recalculate and flip the directions of the normals, but none of these are fixing it.
If I smooth the mesh it looks way more weirder than having it on flat shading.

The mesh keeps its lit faces inside the game engine too.

I'd reconsider making a totally new mesh, but I'm still curious about the faces acting this  way.

Comment: It might be just a blender thing. Try importing it into the game engine and see if the problem persists?

Comment: It would really help if you uploaded the file. What rendering engine are you using? What display/shading method are you on? Where is the light source relative to the door, and what kind of light is it?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. Add images image that include your lighting setup. Also please specify what render engine you are using.

Comment: You're probably getting an edge-lighting effect because there's a light in the scene that's almost directly beside and/or above the door; look in the vicinity of the top-right corner of this image.

Comment: Blender Internal engine (shown on screenshots) in Texture shading mode will take lighting into account so that is result from your lamp. I don't have any idea about how the problem persists in the game engine unless you test this in Blender Game engine with the same light conditions. Try adding more lights into the scene (not 20, I mean 1 sun and 1 spot or alike)

Comment: Are you talking about the "orange" parts?

Answer (score 1):

First [image]off, you should check where your light is coming from.

If the light is close to the door, the dents of the doorframe might block light, only parts that are raised a bit will catch the light. You could easily check that by placing another light source in the scene.

Another thing you should check is if your normals are ok. You can tell blender to recalculate these when you go into Edit Mode, select the affected faces of the model (should be ok if you just select the entire model) and then press "Recalculate" in the left tab under "Shading/UVs". Flipped Normals can often cause lighting issues in the viewport as well.